# Precompile rails AngularJS assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asset-pipeline

I am trying to compile my Rails app assets using RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile, but this doesn't compile my AngularJS assets, so my console report this:

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/app/views/products/index.html"):
```

My AngularJS assets are under "/assets/app/", so I tried to compile the angular folders by adding following into my production.rb but still not working.

```
 config.assets.precompile += %w(app/* bootstrap/* datatable/* ....
```

I can find the compiled index file under this path:

```
 public/assets/app/views/products/index-2429bd0f8fc0762dcc075e51f0306c5b.html
```

Any idea?

UPDATE

Also tried  config.serve_static_assets = false in production, but it cause more missing assets errors

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked through this in my app by using constants to get the path structure right.

my angular app is journey (yours would obviously be different)

so I declare the angular app as a module

```
this.journey = angular.module('journey', [
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute'
  ]);
```

Then I have a file called `constants.js.erb` where I declare my templates

```
journey.constant('INDEX_TEMPLATE', '<%= asset_path('journeys/journey_index.html')%>');
journey.constant('EDIT_JOURNEY_TEMPLATE', '<%= asset_path('journeys/journey_edit.html') %>');
```

Finally in my services I use the constants declared as the template url

```
journey.config([
    '$routeProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    'INDEX_TEMPLATE',
    'EDIT_JOURNEY_TEMPLATE',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, INDEX_TEMPLATE, EDIT_JOURNEY_TEMPLATE) {
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
      return $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: INDEX_TEMPLATE,
        controller: 'JourneyIndexController'
      })
     }
   ])
```

This way I don't have to worry about where the files are or how rails is organising the routing.

Hope this helps